# This is a Perl script to grep a pattern entered from docx files. Please anybody, please point out my mistakes to make it work?

Tags: perl

```
#!usr/bin/perl
#script: patternsearch.pl : Program to search for specific pattern inside the file.
print ("Prgramme name: $0 \n");

print ("Enter pattern: \n");
chop ($pattern = <STDIN>);

print ("Enter the absolute folder path: \n");
chop ($folder = <STDIN>);

print ("Enter file type: \n");
chop ($filetype = <STDIN>);

die ("pattern not entered??? \n") if ($pattern eq " ");

if ($filetype eq "txt") {
                foreach $search (`find $folder -type f -name "*.$filetype"`) {
                do `grep -H $pattern $search>> patternsearch.txt`;
                }           
            }
else {
    foreach $search (`find $folder -type f -name "*.$filetype"`) {
    do `antiword $search | grep -H $pattern >> patternsearch.txt`;
    }
     }
print ("Taskcompleted \n");
```

Comment: Obvious error is here `do \`grep -H $pattern $search>> patternsearch.txt\`;`. You don't need `do` here. Replace it with just backtick operator: `\`grep -H $pattern $search>> patternsearch.txt\`` and see if the problem disappears. Exact error message would be helpful though.

Answer (score 1):

`*.docx` files are not plain text or even actually XML -- they're zipped bundles of XML and other stuff. You can't grep for text in the zipped file. You could unzip a `*.docx`, and then grep in the contents -- although in my experience the XML is written without line breaks, such that each grep hit would be the entire contents of the document.

Answer (score 0):

You really should

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

at the start of every program, and declare all you variables with `my` at the point of first use. This applies especially if you are asking for help with your program, and will quickly draw attention to a lot of simple mistakes.

You ought to use `chomp` instead of `chop`, as the latter just removes the last character from a string whereas the former checks to see if it is a line terminator (newline) before it removes it.

The only problems I can find is that you don't `chomp` the output from your backtick `find` commands: you should write `chomp $search` before the `grep` or `antiword` commands. Also (to paraphrase Yoda) there is no `do` before a backticks command. Remove that from before `grep` and `antiword` and your program may work.

If you have any further problems, please explain what output you expect, and what you are getting.